# Deleted Document library still shown in Sharepoint Search Results

Tags: search, document-library, document, search-results

I have a document library on a Sharepoint site. From this library, **I have deleted a particular document**. It has also been removed from recycle bin. But the problem is, when **this document is searched, it shows in the search result**.
What can be done to prevent it from showing in search result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check to be sure that content source has been crawled again since deleting the document library.  If, after at least two crawls, it still appears in search results, you will need to reset your Search Index.

Comment: Here is a quick how to on resetting your index: http://sharepointnoob.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/reset-crawled-content-in-moss-2007/